# Call notifyDataSetChanged after each item I receive in AsyncTask

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I use an `AsyncTask` and on `doInBackground()` I have a loop where I'm doing a lot of network calls. Each call gives me a new data object that I want to add it to my `listView`.

I know that I can call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on `onPostExecute()` and update my list with all my items but I'm wondering if its possible to somehow call `notifyDataSetChanged()` when I receive a new item and update my `listView` the same moment and not to have to wait until all the work on `doInBackground` finishes.

If there isn't a way I can do this with AsyncTask then whats the proper way to deal with something like that?

Thank you

Comment: You can use Volley library for the same. Where you can setup RequestQueue and in onResponse method can update the listview. For request queue setup, follow this link. http://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `publishProgress(...)` from `doInBackground(...)` and override `onProgressUpdate(...)` in your `AsyncTask` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` there.

Calling `publishProgress(...)` from `doInBackground(...)` instructs the `AsyncTask` to call it's `onProgressUpdate(...)` on the main UI thread, hence you can update the `ListView` from there.

Comment: Just a little note, since adapter is being notified at each insert, instead of notifyDataSetChanged() notifyItemInsterted() can be called.

Comment: @RusheelJain +1 but I believe `notifyItemInsterted(...)` works only for `RecyclerView` and @Mes is using `ListView`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @camelCaseCoder I think you are right since I can't find `notifyItemInsterted();`

Comment: @camelCaseCoder I think you are right. It is recyclerView's feature.